# Remove list view link for community members on record list page

Tags: community, css

We are using a "Full" record list in a Salesforce Community and would still like to be able to disable the drop down menu for changing the list view. There is only one list view this group should be using. I was able to hide the down icon to select the list view with CSS but the list view name still shows as a link and allows it to be clicked on. Other than changing this to a Standard layout, is there a way to change this in CSS to prevent the drop-down of list views from showing? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a community, you can have a custom component with below code and use it in required community page.

```
<lightning:listView aura:id="listViewAccounts"
                    objectApiName="Account"
                    listName="AllAccounts"
                    rows="5"
                    showSearchBar="true"
                    showActionBar="true"
                    enableInlineEdit="true"
                    showRowLevelActions="true"
                    />
```

and below CSS:

```
.THIS .listViewTitle>a {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    color:black;
}
```

This will render only 1 list view and CSS will disable the click on name so that it does not go to standard list view.

Comment: That is helpful, thanks @salesforcesas

Comment: WC. pls mark it as solved/accepted if solved